# Displaying text inside a control element with type edit

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Pretty simple: I would like to have a edit-field where there is already text inside (a kind of default value) but which is also editable.
I tried a lot of different version but nothing wanted to work yet.

This is the last version I tried (the checkbox works just fine):

```
<Property Id="MYPROPERTY" Value="default" />
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="ConfigVariablesDlg" Width="370" Height="270">
                <Control Type="Edit" Id="InputField" Property="MYPROPERTY" X="125" Y="27" Width="100" Height="15" Indirect="yes" Text="[MYPROPERTY]">
                    <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[EnableBox<>"1"]]></Condition>
                    <Condition Action="enable">EnableBox="1"</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Type="CheckBox" Id="MyBox" Width="10" Height="10" X="110" Y="30" Property="EnableBox" CheckBoxValue="1"/>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you define your property you simply have to assigne it a value like this

```
<Property Id="MYPROPERTY">Text you want to fill in</Property>
```

So you cut away your Value Field from your `Control` Element and define your Property beforehand. (Still Inside your UI Element!)

So in the end your code should look something like this

```
<UI>
    <Property Id="MYPROPERTY">Text you want to fill in</property>
    <Dialog Id="ConfigVariablesDlg" Width="370" Height="270">
        <Control Type="Edit" Id="InputField" Property="MYPROPERTY" X="125" Y="27" Width="100" Height="15" Indirect="yes">
            <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[EnableBox<>"1"]]></Condition>
            <Condition Action="enable">EnableBox="1"</Condition>
        </Control>
        <Control Type="CheckBox" Id="MyBox" Width="10" Height="10" X="110" Y="30" Property="EnableBox" CheckBoxValue="1"/>
    </Dialog>
```

*edit also I am pretty (but not entirely sure)

```
![CDATA[EnableBox<>"1"]]
```

should be

```
![CDATA[EnableBox<>1]]
```

atleast thats how it worked for me